# Genetically altered seeds escape in Bay area; genetically altered children spontaneously suicide

Tags: story-identification, books, genetic-engineering

Read a book in the 1980’s that warns of the dangers of genetic engineering. My memory is very vague as to details, but I seem to recall the book opening with modified grass or rice seeds that proliferate in the S.F. Bay area, causing problems. Later, parents can choose to alter their fetus' genetics, eliminating such things as diseases and alcoholism, as a well as increasing intelligence. Still later in the book, these children can spontaneously suicide.

Comment: Be part about the children's spontaneously suiciding reminds me of another one we had here where it was all girls in a high school, where a particular genetic strain was having that issue. If I recall correctly, the protagonist was also from that strain which made her all the more motivated to solve the mystery.